# Is BrokeredMessage Supported in java for Azure Function Service bus triggers?

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

I was wondering if there is a way to to accessed the BrokeredMessage of a ServiceBusQueueTrigger. It looks like it's supported for C#, but not for java. Is there a way to get that related info.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation._service_bus_queue_trigger?view=azure-java-stable

I want to be able to get info like the correlation id.

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BrokeredMessage is not supported currently. However, the correlation ID is exposed as binding metadata (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---message-metadata)). You need to use  [Java client library for Azure Service Bus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java) to work with any strong types such as BrokeredMessage. Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java#data-type-support) for supported types in Java Functions.